# azure pipeline - how to pass certificate to pipeline agent

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to push docker image to registry on nexus using azure pipeline.
my nexus uses self signed certificate.
when I tried to push I got the following error:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Since I don't have root privileges on the pipeline agent,
I CANNOT (for example) create a 'command line script' task to run the commands:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myserver:port < /dev/null |  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
update-ca-certificates -f
```

**how can I make the agent to trust my self signed certificate?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we can use the [Secure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) to store the signing certificates. Secure files are defined and managed in the Library tab in Azure Pipelines.

Then we can use the [Download Secure File Utility task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to consume secure files within a Build or Release Pipeline. You can have a try for that.

If that doesn't work. I am afraid that you have to [setup a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) to do that.

Comment: thanks very much . I'm going to try the self hosted agent

Comment: Yeah, please try the self hosted agent, you can do anything what you want to since you own it.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank u very much :-) . self hosted agent solved this issue.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT - what if the secure file being downloaded is a self signed pfx file with a password on it?