# azure devops deployment issue getting error at deploy stage as:- tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

i am getting this error

##[error]Unable to connect to the server: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca")

how do i fix it?

my kubernetes server version is Server Version: v1.21.9
and client is Client Version: v1.28.2

i am using azure devops for deployment and azure cloud for my kubernetes cluster

i am expecting that the cluster deploys my code on the cluster

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you checked your [Kubernetes service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#service-account-option)? This problem may be that your service connection has expired. You can try to create a new service connection and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` indicates that the certificate used by the server is not trusted by the client. To fix this issue, you need to [add the certificate to the trusted root store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61776409/azure-pipeline-how-to-pass-certificate-to-pipeline-agent) of the client machine.

Option A- If your Kubernetes cluster uses a certificate signed by a well-known CA, ensure that the entire certificate chain is correctly installed on the Kubernetes API server.

Option B- If your Kubernetes cluster is using a private CA or self-signed certificate, you can import the certificate to the agent running the deployment if you have control over it.

But before all this, verify if your [Kubernetes service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#service-account-option) has expired as Miao suggested or if you're running `kubectl` commands in your pipeline, I would request you to try `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` flag to bypass the certificate verification. Example `kubectl  get  nodes  --insecure-skip-tls-verify` to [bypass the certificate verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150437/getting-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-even-with-insecure-sk). This is not recommended for production but can help you identify if the issue is solely due to the certificate trust.

[image]

You can export the root certificate from the server and add it to the trusted root store of the client machine. For example, if you are using Azure DevOps, you can follow the steps outlined in the "[Configure the self-signed certificates in Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/devops/git-clone-push-operation-failing-devops-repo#solution-2-configure-the-self-signed-certificates-in-git)" section of the -   [Troubleshoot issues when Git clone or push fails to an Azure DevOps repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/devops/git-clone-push-operation-failing-devops-repo#cause-2-git-uses-a-local-self-signed-certificate) article.

Once you have exported the certificate, you can add it to the trusted root store of the client machine. You can follow the steps outlined in the "[Add a certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store for a local computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate)" section of the Microsoft documentation.